# Core Data slice plotting style

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I need to plot pie chart using core plot in following slice way i.e slice at some distance.

please suggest me some way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i hope if it helps you [Using Core Plot in an iPhone Application](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 1):

Implement the following method in your datasource:

```
-(CGFloat)radialOffsetForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart
                      recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

See the donut chart example in the Plot Gallery app for a sample.

Comment: Thanks Eric.it worked nice. But how can i do it for click on slice in animate way?any idea

Comment: You could start a repeating timer when the user clicks a pie slice. Call `-setNeedsDisplay` on the plot and return a slightly larger offset value each time the timer fires. Stop the timer when the offset reaches the desired final value.